# Getting date value from improper formats using excel

Tags: excel, vba

Need a small help. I am pulling a report from a tool but for some reason, some of the date value in the Close date/time column appears properly but rest appear in some random format. I am unable to perform any date formulas on this cell and manually changing cell format to date doesn't work either. Can you please help let me know steps to clean this data?

Sample file link mentioned below

[Sample file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aTOK8zcWk_18d2K0zNZz6rvJXo1Uxnfu/view?usp=sharing)

As suggested by @Olly, providing my steps tried till now in new excel

[Formulas tried till now](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NvBW-QnmXOyYc4KNFvjMM0aI-OE02v26)

Problem I am facing here is joining date and time again and then identifying which cells had right data and which have wrong.

Thanks,
Anup

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? [Edit] your question to show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text to Columns, Fixed width, Remove extra column markers, MDY, Finish.

[image]